# не правильно считает с++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

При сложение вычитании выводит не несуразицу

```
Создаем вектор
получаем элемент массива
Выводим элемент на экран: 2
0 1 2 3 4
Сложение: 12 13 14 15 16
Вычитание: 4 5 6 7 8
Умножение:
```

а при умножении ошибку

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

---

Vector.h

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>;

class Vector{
public:
    //конструктор без параметров
    Vector(){
        length=1;
        vector = new int*[length];//выделяем место для одного элемента
        vector[0]= (int *) 0;//и инициализирует его в ноль
    };

    //конструктор с параметром
    Vector(int len){
        if (! len < 1) {
            length = len;
            vector = new int *[length];//выделяет место аргументом
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                vector[i] = (int *) i;//инициализирует номером элемента в массиве
        }else{
            printf("Не верное значение длинны массива");
        }
    };

    //конструктор с двумя параметрами
    Vector(int len,int value){
        if (! len < 1) {
            length = len;
            vector = new int *[length];//выделяет место первым аргументом
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                vector[i] = (int *) value;//инициализируем вторым аргументом
        }else{
            printf("Не верное значение длинны массива");
        }
    };

    //присваивает элементу массива некоторое значение (определить номер и новое значение элемента)
    int SetVectorItem(int item, int value){
        if (item >=0 && item < length)
            vector[item] = (int *) value;
    }

    //функция которая получает некоторый элемент массива
    int GetVectorItem(int i){
        if(i>0&&i<length){
            return (int)vector[i-1];
        }else{
            printf("За пределами массива");
        }
        return i;
    };

    //Определить функцию печати.
    void PrintAllItems(){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            std::cout<<(int)vector[i]<<" ";
        printf("\n");
    }

    void PrintItem(int i){
        if(i>0&&i<length)
            printf("%i\n", vector[i-1]);
    }

    //Определить функции сложения
    void Add(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] += value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Определить функции вычитания
    void Sub(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] -= value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Определить функции умножения
    void Mul(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] = (int *) (*vector[i] * value);//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Деструктор освобождает память.
    ~Vector(){
        delete vector;// память освобождается
        vector = NULL;// указатель заменяется на 0 (нуль-указатель)
    }
private:
    int length = 0;
    int **vector;
    int states;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Vector.h"

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(65001);// установка кодировки для ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);// установка кодировки для вывода

    printf("Создаем вектор\n");
    Vector *v1 = new Vector(5);

    printf("получаем элемент массива\n");
    int value = v1->GetVectorItem(3);
    printf("Выводим элемент на экран: %i \n", value);

    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Сложение: ");
    v1->Add(3);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Вычитание: ");
    v1->Sub(2);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Умножение: ");
//    v1->Mul(2);
//    v1->PrintAllItems();

    delete v1;
//    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Интересно, зачем (даже вот так - ***ЗАЧЕМ???!!!!***) - вы использовали `int**vector`?

Вобщем, забирайте. Но у вас много жути. Конструктор обязан либо создать объект, либо сгенерировать исключение. У вас - просто вывод сообщения.

Зачем-то в ряде случаев вы начинаете цикл не с нуля, вобщем, какие-то странности.

Смешивать `cout` и `printf` в одной программе - некрасиво.

И еще куча мелочей...

```
class Vector{
public:
    //конструктор без параметров
    Vector(){
        length=1;
        vector = new int[length];//выделяем место для одного элемента
        vector[0] = 0;//и инициализирует его в ноль
    };

    //конструктор с параметром
    Vector(int len){
        if (len>= 1) {
            length = len;
            vector = new int[length];//выделяет место аргументом
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                vector[i] = i;//инициализирует номером элемента в массиве
        }else{
            printf("Неверное значение длинны массива");

            //!!!! В результате вектор НЕИНИЦИАЛИЗИРОВАН!!!
        }
    };

    //конструктор с двумя параметрами
    Vector(int len,int value){
        if (len >= 1) {
            length = len;
            vector = new int[length];//выделяет место первым аргументом
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                vector[i] = value;//инициализируем вторым аргументом
        }else{
            printf("Неверное значение длинны массива");
            //!!!! В результате вектор НЕИНИЦИАЛИЗИРОВАН!!!
        }
    };

    //присваивает элементу массива некоторое значение (определить номер и новое значение элемента)
    int SetVectorItem(int item, int value){
        if (item >=0 && item < length)
            vector[item] = value;
    }

    //функция которая получает некоторый элемент массива
    int GetVectorItem(int i){
        if(i>=0 && i<length){
            return vector[i];
        }else{
            printf("За пределами массива");
        }
        return i;
    };

    //Определить функцию печати.
    void PrintAllItems(){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            std::cout<< vector[i] << " ";
        std::cout<< std::endl;
    }

    void PrintItem(int i){
        if(i>=0 && i<length)
            std::cout << vector[i] << std::endl;
    }

    //Определить функции сложения
    void Add(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] += value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Определить функции вычитания
    void Sub(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] -= value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Определить функции умножения
    void Mul(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] *= value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Деструктор освобождает память.
    ~Vector(){
        delete[] vector;// память освобождается
    }
private:
    int length = 0;
    int *vector;
    int states;
};


int main() {

    printf("Создаем вектор\n");
    Vector *v1 = new Vector(5);

    printf("получаем элемент массива\n");
    int value = v1->GetVectorItem(3);
    printf("Выводим элемент на экран: %i \n", value);

    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Сложение: ");
    v1->Add(3);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Вычитание: ");
    v1->Sub(2);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Умножение: ");
    v1->Mul(2);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    delete v1;
    //    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь)))
"Смешивать cout и printf в одной программе - некрасиво."
Я плох в с++, думал проблемма в методе вывода и тестировал разные способы.

"Конструктор обязан либо создать объект, либо сгенерировать исключение. У вас - просто вывод сообщения."
Он создает объект или выводит сообщение о неправильном параметре. Если можете предложить хорошее решение этого то я был бы благодарен. Улучшать свои навыки я всегда рад.

"Зачем-то в ряде случаев вы начинаете цикл не с нуля, вобщем, какие-то странности." 
пересмотрел код так и не нашел где он начинается не с нуля.

Comment: При неправильных параметрах получается, что вы не можете использовать объект - он не создан. Его внутренняя структура не самосогласована, указатели указывают непонятно куда и т.д. Если вы просто выведете сообщение, программа все равно будет считать, что этот объект можно использовать. В таком случае следует геенрировать исключение; если вы еще с ними незнакомы - то лучше после вывода сообщения завершать программу `exit(1)`, или `abort()`. О "не с нуля" -  например `if(i>0&&i<length)` - т.е. один элемент все равно будет не выведен...

Comment: еще пара вопросов если можно:
В условии задачи еще стоит
----------------------------------------------------------
В переменную состояния устанавливать код ошибки, когда не хватает памяти, выходит за пределы массива. 
Предусмотреть возможность подсчета числа объектов данного типа
----------------------------------------------------------
Для подсчета я нашел вот это sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0]) но оно не работает

Comment: Ну при каждой проверке, если что не так - устанавливайте эту переменную. Общее количество объектов - добавьте в класс `static int count = 0;` и в *каждом* конструкторе (придется написать копирующий) увеличивайте на 1, в деструкторе - уменьшайте. Вот и счетчик...

Answer (score 3):

Вы, не понятно зачем, создаете вектор указателей, содержащих недействительные адреса, как, например, 0, а затем в функции `Mul` пытаетесь их разыменовать

```
void Mul(int value){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        vector[i] = (int *) (*vector[i] * value);//с данными этого класса и целым числом
                             ^^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

В результате происходит обращение к памяти, которая не принадлежит вашей программе, и программа имеет неопределенное поведение.
Нет никакого смысла для вашей программы определять вектор указателей. Нужно определять вектор целочисленных значений.

Член класса `length` следует объявить, как имеющую беззнаковый целочисленный тип. Например, вы могли бы объявить ее, как имеющую тип `size_t`. Зачем вы сами себе создаете трудности, объявляя этот член класса знаковым, чтобы затем каждый раз проверять, не задал ли пользователь  отрицательное число?

Член класса `state` нигде в классе не используется. Поэтому его можно удалить из определения класса.

Для пустого вектора вообще не надо выделять память под элементы. На о он и пустой вектор. Поэтому конструктор по умолчанию следует объявить следующим образом

```
Vector() : length( 0 ), vector( nullptr ) {}
```

Конструктор с параметром изначально полностью неверный.

```
Vector(int len){
    if (! len < 1) {
        length = len;
        vector = new int *[length];//выделяет место аргументом
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] = (int *) i;//инициализирует номером элемента в массиве
    }else{
        printf("Не верное значение длинны массива");
    }
};
```

Во-первых, данное условие в `if` предложении

```
if (! len < 1) {
    ^^^^^^^^
```

эквивалетно следующему условию

```
if ( (! len) < 1) {
    ^^^^^^^^
```

Выражение `!len` всегда будет равно `true`, когда `Len` не равно 0, даже если `len` содержит отрицательное число. Кроме того, конструктор оставляет объект класса в неопределенном состоянии, если `len` было равно 0, а также имеет неопределенное поведение, когда `len` было задано отрицательным числом.

То же самое справедливо и для конструктора с двумя параметрами.

Функция `SetVectorItem` объявлена, как имеющая тип `int`

```
int SetVectorItem(int item, int value){
    if (item >=0 && item < length)
        vector[item] = (int *) value;
}
```

Однако она ничего не возвращает.

Другая функция, функция `GetVectorItem`, противоречит предыдущей функции.

```
int GetVectorItem(int i){
    if(i>0&&i<length){
        return (int)vector[i-1];
    }else{
        printf("За пределами массива");
    }
    return i;
};
```

В первой функции аргумент для индекса задается, начиная с 0

```
    if (item >=0 && item < length)
             ^^^
```

тогда как во второй функции аргумент для индекса задается, начиная с 1

```
    if(i>0&&i<length){
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

и кроме того последний элемент в таком случае всегда будет не доступен. К тому же функция может вернуть значение `i`, которое может лишь запутывать пользователя функции.

Такое же неверное условие проверки индекса и у функции `PrintItem`

```
void PrintItem(int i){
    if(i>0&&i<length)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        printf("%i\n", vector[i-1]);
}
```

Так что вам следует устроить полную ревизию определения класса.

Если по каким-то причинам, например, из учебных целей, вам  надо создавать указатель на указатели, то вам следует для каждого элемента также выделять память. Например,

```
Vector( size_t len ) : length( len ), vector( nullptr )
{
    if ( length != 0 ) 
    {
        vector = new int * [length];
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        {
            vector[i] = new int( i ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень информативно. А про конструктор по умолчанию было следующее условие. **"Конструктор без параметров выделяет место для одного элемента и инициализирует его в ноль."**

Comment: @Ghost Это несколько не логично, но может иметь место.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще чтобы не путать людей выложу полное тз:

```
        Создать абстрактный тип данных - класс вектор 
(число элементов, элементы и переменная состояния). 
    Определить конструктор без параметров, конструктор 
с параметром, конструктор с двумя параметрами. Конструктор без 
параметров выделяет место для одного элемента и инициализирует 
его в ноль. Конструктор с одним параметром, - количество элементов
вектора, - выделяет место и инициализирует номером элемента 
в массиве, конструктор с двумя параметрами выделяет место 
(первый аргумент – количество элементов) и инициализирует вторым аргументом. 
    Деструктор освобождает память. 
    Определить функцию, которая присваивает элементу массива некоторое 
значение (определить номер и новое значение элемента), функцию которая 
получает некоторый элемент массива. В переменную состояния устанавливать 
код ошибки, когда не хватает памяти, выходит за пределы массива. 
Определить функцию печати. Определить функции сложения, умножения, 
вычитания, которые производят эти арифметические операции с данными 
этого класса и целым числом. Определить методы сравнения: больше, 
меньше или равно. Предусмотреть возможность подсчета числа объектов 
данного типа. Проверить работу этого класса.

и то что у меня получилось, не уверен что правильно:
```

**Vector.h**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>;
static int count = 0;//Предусмотреть возможность подсчета числа объектов данного типа
class Vector{
public:
    //конструктор без параметров
    Vector(){
        length=1;
        vector = new int[length];//выделяем место для одного элемента
        vector[0] = 0;//и инициализирует его в ноль
        count++;//Увеличиваем количество объектов
    };

    //конструктор с параметром
    Vector(int len){
        if (len > 0) {
            length = len;
            vector = new int[length];//выделяет место аргументом
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                vector[i] = i;//инициализирует номером элемента в массиве
            count++;//Увеличиваем количество объектов
        }else{
            printf("Неверное значение длинны массива");
            abort();
        }
    };

    //конструктор с двумя параметрами
    Vector(int len,int value){
        if (len > 0) {
            length = len;
            vector = new int[length];//выделяет место первым аргументом
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                vector[i] = value;//инициализируем вторым аргументом
            count++;//Увеличиваем количество объектов
        }else{
            printf("Неверное значение длинны массива");
            abort();
        }
    };

    //Деструктор освобождает память.
    ~Vector(){
        delete[] vector;// память освобождается
        count--;//Уменьшаем количество объектов
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    //присваивает элементу массива некоторое значение (определить номер и новое значение элемента)
    int SetVectorItem(int item, int value){
        if (item >=0 && item < length)
            vector[item] = value;
    }

    //функция которая получает некоторый элемент массива
    int GetVectorItem(int i){
        if(i>=0 && i<length){
            return vector[i];
        }else{
            printf("За пределами массива");
        }
        return i;
    };

    //---------------------------------------
    //Определить функцию печати.
    void PrintAllItems(){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            printf("%i ",vector[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    void PrintItem(int i){
        if(i>=0 && i<length)
            printf("%i \n",vector[i]);
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    //Определить функции сложения
    void Add(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] += value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Определить функции вычитания
    void Sub(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] -= value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //Определить функции умножения
    void Mul(int value){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            vector[i] *= value;//с данными этого класса и целым числом
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    //Определить методы сравнения:

    //больше
    void Larger(int a, int b){
        if (vector[a]>vector[b]) {
            printf("Больше\n");
        }
    }

    //меньше
    void Less (int a, int b){
        if (vector[a]<vector[b]) {
            printf("Меньше\n");
        }
    }

    //равно
    void Equ (int a, int b){
        if (vector[a]==vector[b]) {
            printf("Равно\n");
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------------
    //Предусмотреть возможность подсчета числа объектов данного типа.
    int GetCountObjectsVector(){
        return count;
    }


private:
    int length = 0;
    int *vector;
    int states;

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Vector.h"

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(65001);// установка кодировки для ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);// установка кодировки для вывода

    int a,b;

    printf("Создаем вектор\n");
    Vector *v1 = new Vector(8);
    printf("Введите два числа через пробел: ");
    std::cin>>a>>b;
    printf("a = %i, b = %i\n",a,b);

    printf("получаем элемент массива: %i \n",v1->GetVectorItem(a));

    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Сложение: ");
    v1->Add(a);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Вычитание: ");
    v1->Sub(a);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    printf("Умножение: ");
    v1->Mul(a);
    v1->PrintAllItems();

    //методы сравнения:
    v1->Larger(a,b);
    v1->Less(a,b);
    v1->Equ(a,b);

    printf("Колличество объектов: %i", v1->GetCountObjectsVector());

    delete v1;
    //    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```